# Using list in other class

Tags: java

I want to you use my LinkedList in another class. But everytime I try to use my command the list I get outputs where the command says it's already empty, which is not the case.

```
package commands;

import com.jagrosh.jdautilities.command.Command;
import com.jagrosh.jdautilities.command.CommandEvent;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Subscribe extends Command {

    public Subscribe() {
        this.name = "subscribe";
        this.help = "Subscribe channel to alert trades.";
        this.cooldown = 5;
    }

    public LinkedList<String> subscription = new LinkedList<String>();

    public LinkedList<String> getList() {
        return subscription;
    }

    protected void execute(CommandEvent event) {
        if (!(subscription.contains("<#" + event.getChannel().getId() + ">"))) {
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Succesfully subscribed channel <#" + event.getChannel().getId() + ">.").queue();
            subscription.add("<#" + event.getChannel().getId() + ">");
        } else {
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("This channel is already subscribed, please execute $unsubscribe to unsubscribe this channel!").queue();
        }
    }
}
```

^^ This is the code where I made the class.

```
package commands;

import com.jagrosh.jdautilities.command.Command;
import com.jagrosh.jdautilities.command.CommandEvent;
import sun.awt.image.ImageWatched;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Unsubscribe extends Command {

    public Unsubscribe() {
        this.name = "unsubscribe";
        this.help = "Unsubscribe channel to stop alerting trades.";
        this.cooldown = 5;
    }

    Subscribe subscribe = new Subscribe();
    LinkedList<String> subscription2 = new LinkedList<>(subscribe.getList());


    protected void execute(CommandEvent event) {
        if (subscription2.contains("<#" + event.getChannel().getId() + ">")) {
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Succesfully unsubscribed channel <#" + event.getChannel().getId() + ">.").queue();
            subscription2.remove("<#" + event.getChannel().getId() + ">");
        } else {
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("This channel is already unsubscribed, please execute $subscribe to subscribe this channel!").queue();
        }


    }
}
```

^^ This is the piece of code where I want to use the same LinkedList.

Comment: `subscribe.getList()` is correct... What's the issue?

Comment: It's a JDA bot. And I want to subscribe to the a certain channel. If it is subscribed ($subscribe) it says subscribed and adds it to the list. But now I want to unsubscribe the channel and it says it's already unsubscribed, while it is subscribed.

Answer (score 0):

`subscription2` is a brand new instance of a `LinkedList` that is only created when `new Unsubscribe()` is created, and unrelated to the values used in the other class.

At creation time, `Subscription.subscription` is empty, and `getList()` returns the same empty list.

---

You don't need `subscription2`, you can always refer to `subscribe.getList().contains`/ `remove`, etc

You should also make the `LinkedList` a private field in the Subscription class

---

A better way to manage this would be decouple the two classes, and use an [Observer Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer) with a third class that holds the actual subscription list, and the sub/unsub commands delete actions to it via interfaces

Comment: I replaced subscription 2 with subscribe.getList().contains but I still get the same output.

Comment: Well, then `execute` is never called or your if statements aren't correct

Comment: The subscribe part works and if I subscribe after it is subscribed it says "This channel is already subscribed." So the list works. I just need to call the list to my other class.

Comment: And that's what `subscribe.getList()` will do, assuming that you maintain the same instance of `subscribe` throughout the code